# Run an file after X seconds when running the .bat file

Tags: command-line

I wonder if there is any way that i can run an file after X seconds when i run the .bat file

I have search for an example but didn't help

```
@echo off
sleep 10
start "C:\file.txt"
exit
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From a BAT file I use regularly:

```
REM - Wait 10 seconds
CHOICE /C:AB /T:10 /D:A > NUL
```

I don't recall where I got it, probably SuperUser.  I've been using it for years, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`timeout`](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) function:

```
C:\> timeout 10
```

The bat file will be something like:

```
@echo off
timeout 10
start "C:\file.txt"
exit
```

Comment: How exactly can you please give me the hole .bat code?

Comment: This does not work man i try this @echo off
timeout 5
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe"
exit but not working